# update_all through an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to use update_all through an association, and i am getting mysql errors, anyone know why please?

```
class Basket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :basket_items
  has_many :articles, :through => :basket_items

  def activate_articles
    articles.update_all :active => true
  end
end

class BasketItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :basket
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :article
end


Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'basket_items.basket_id' in 'where clause': UPDATE `articles` SET `active` = 1 WHERE ((`basket_items`.basket_id = 114))
```

Comment: Looks like your `basket_items` table isn't set up correctly. Can you show us the schema?

Comment: Thanks for looking Daniel, i have updated my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/5353

Looks like there was a problem with n-n associations using has_many :through and using update all. Nothing seems to have been done.

1-n associations do appear to work.

Bug?

Answer (score 2):

dev.rubyonrails moved it's tickets to github's issue tracker.  Here is the moved link:  https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/522

@nolman posted this help on the ticket

> @daicoden and I at @square were pairing on this and we were able to put something together along the lines of:
>
> ```
> class Comment
>   class << self
>     def trash_all
>       sql = "UPDATE #{quoted_table_name} "
>       add_joins!(sql, {})
>       sql << "SET #{sanitize_sql_for_assignment({:trashed => true})} "
>       add_conditions!(sql, {})
>       connection.execute(sql)
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> Now you can call todolist.comments(:conditions => {:trashed => false}).trash_all
>   This results in the following SQL:
>
> ```
> UPDATE `comments` INNER JOIN `todos` ON `todos`.id = `comments`.todo_id SET `trashed` = 1 WHERE (`comments`.`trashed` = 0 AND `todos`.`todolist_id` = 968316918)
> ```
>
> Hope this helps!