# How to associate many users with one message at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have posts that associated with many users. When somebody comment one of them, my app creates a message that should be delivered to users associated with post. I want to associate all commented post users with new message. How to do it at once, without iterator?

```
users.each do |user| 
  user.messages << message
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not achievable with standard rails syntax, but you are still free to use plain old good SQL:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute %Q{
  UPDATE users
  SET message_id = #{message.id}
  WHERE post_id = #{post.id}
}
```

The query above is likely not precisely correct, since you did not provide the relationship model, but I guess you get the point.

Comment: you can do that using active record. `User.where(post: post).update_all(message: message)` or `User.where(post_id: post_id).update_all(message_id: message_id)`, but I am not sure if this is what he asked for.

Comment: @NafaaBoutefer : I have just post the answer with same solution. After hitting post I see you have commented the same. You bit me wid 50 sec :D

Comment: I believe OP should mark the answer by @GaganGami as correct, since it provides more railsyish solution.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are looking for **[ActiveRecord::Base.update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class)** - from the documentation:

> Updates all records with details given if they match a set of
>   conditions supplied, limits and order can also be supplied. This
>   method constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and sends it straight
>   to the database. It does not instantiate the involved models and it
>   does not trigger Active Record callbacks.

you can do something like:

```
users.update_all(:messages => "your message")
```

I guess you have all users related the same post in your `users` object.

for your reference you can check this link too regarding **[update_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all)**:

> Updates all records in the current relation with details given. This
>   method constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and sends it straight
>   to the database. It does not instantiate the involved models and it
>   does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations. Values passed
>   to `update_all` will not go through ActiveRecord's type-casting
>   behavior. It should receive only values that can be passed as-is to
>   the SQL database.

Comment: It's good answer! But I have HABTM relation between Users & Messages so I need to update table users_messages with user_ids + message_id. Will it work in this case?

Comment: @nobilik : checkout this same question asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833529/update-all-through-an-association

Answer (score 0):

I saw this answer [Can you supply arguments to the map(&:method) syntax in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695653/can-you-supply-arguments-to-the-mapmethod-syntax-in-ruby)

I do not recommend it but your can hack your way around by `monkey patching` the `Symbol` class in your `initializer` like

```
class Symbol
  def call(*args, &block)
    ->(caller, *rest) { caller.send(self, *rest, *args, &block) }
  end
end
```

and in your User model adding a simple method like

```
def addMessage(message)
   self.messages << message
end
```

and in your code simply replace this

```
users.each do |user| 
  user.messages << message
end
```

with

```
users.map(&:addMessage.(message))
```

## this is actually the same thing but it hides away the iterative style code to a simple `map`

## I would **NOT** recommend doing this but I found it rather fun to play around with.

Comment: Besides this is a nasty trick, that should be avoided, this approach _still calls `each`_ (implicitly, in `map`.) The question was about avoiding loops.

Comment: @mudasobwa I non recommended it like 2 times and mentioned the same thing in the ending statement .. It was just a fun way of doing I found and shared it. but as it goes its not recommended

Comment: My comment was not about “not recommending,” since it starts with “besides.” `map` by no means differs from `each`, that’s why this trick actually just senseless in terms of answering the original question.

Comment: @nobilik it sure is.. :P